# Using .before() and .after() to wrap multiple elements in a parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create the following arrangement:
[image]

Each element must be a square. The squares 1, 4, and 7 are 25% of the total width each, and the remainder are 12.5% wide each. Heights are the same as widths, of course.

Typically this would be trivial, but I am outputting these elements from an API. They output fine, but due to the dynamic nature of this, I'm not sure how exactly to make sure that they come into the desired arrangement.

I suspected that the most straightforward way is to have 1, 4, and 7 as regular div elements, and 2/3 and 5/6 to each be in a containing div. These containers would carry a 100% height and 12.5% width each, and the interior div elements 2/3 and 5/6 would have a 100% width and 50% height each.

Each element has the class `my-div-quarter` by default. For elements 2 and 5, I make an opening div tag. For elements 3 and 6, I close this div. I also remove the `my-div-quarter` class from each interior element 2, 3, 5, and 6.

I have the following loop acting on all of these elements:

```
$('.my-div').each(function(index){
  if (index === 1 || index === 4){
    $(this).before("<div class='my-div my-div-eighth'>");
    $(this).removeClass('my-div-quarter');
  }
  else if (index === 2 || index === 5){
    $(this).removeClass('my-div-quarter');
    $(this).after("</div>");
  }
});
```

Then I have the following CSS:

```
 .my-div-quarter {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .my-div-eighth {
    width: 12.5%;
    div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
    }
  }
```

It *almost* works, but for some reason, the `my-div-eighth` elements just close up without containing the interior elements. Any ideas?

Comment: lets try to put this into an actual working example. I'll try to do this on my end. you try to do this on your end.

Comment: Doing this with css flex would make it trivial

Comment: Will there always be 7 items? If so, `nth-child(){}` will probably have you covered.

Comment: Can you please post the `html` also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use flex so you don't have to worry about opening/closing div as all of them will be the same :

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:155px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.5%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item:nth-child(1),
.item:nth-child(4),
.item:nth-child(7) {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow;
}

.item:nth-child(3),
.item:nth-child(6) {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
</div>
```

If want to make it responsive you may add this jQuery code that will adapt dynamically the height of the container to keep the square ratio :

```
$( ".container" ).css( 'height',$( ".container" ).width()/4);

$( window ).resize(function() {
  $( ".container" ).css( 'height',$( ".container" ).width()/4);
});
```

Comment: I'm confused because original post says 'must be squares' I'm not sure if he means that literally equal sided squares

Comment: @NickTimmer yes you are right. It will also depend if it needs to be responsive or not. As i can simply update the height to obtain the square (i did it) but not sure how it should behave.

Comment: Works perfectly! It does need to be responsive but I can just stack them in the mobile layout and have them exactly equal sizes. Just the desktop was giving me trouble. Thanks!

Comment: @AKor welcome, i was also thinking about using resize event with jQuery and change dynamicly the height of the container, as you may notice it should alwyas be `width / 4`

Comment: @AKor updated my anwer to make it responsive ;) added the jQuery code you may have a try

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.lrg-square {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  float: left
}

.md-container {
  width: 12.5%;
  float: left;
}

.sm-square {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: #52FF26;
}

.sm-square:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #F40039;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='lrg-square'>
  <div class='content'>1</div>
</div>
<div class='md-container'>
  <div class='sm-square'>
    <div class='content'>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='sm-square'>
    <div class='content'>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='lrg-square'>
  <div class='content'>4</div>
</div>
<div class='md-container'>
  <div class='sm-square'>
    <div class='content'>5</div>
  </div>
  <div class='sm-square'>
    <div class='content'>6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='lrg-square'>
  <div class='content'>7</div>
</div>
```

just for comparison to Temani Afif's already accepted correct answer using flex-box.
This is just using css, i like flex-box better.

Comment: This was mostly inspired by a post I read here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/14/css-responsive-square/